# pgfplots: addplot3 color particular planes

Tags: pgfplots

using `\addplot3` how do you shade in particular planes?

e.g., If we consider the unit cube, I want to shade the plane `x = 1`,`y = 1`, `z = 1`.

This is all I've got so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[fill=blue]{x=1, y=1, z=1};
coordinates{
(1,0,0)
(0,1,0)
(0,0,1)
};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={20}{10}]
\addplot3[fill=blue]
coordinates{
(1,0,0)
(1,1,0)
(1,1,1)
(1,0,1)
};

%\addplot3[fill=red]
%coordinates{
%(0,1,0)
%(1,1,0)
%(1,1,1)
%(0,1,1)
%};

\addplot3[fill=magenta]
coordinates{
(0,0,1)
(0,1,1)
(1,1,1)
(1,0,1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]